# Problema con el envio de unos datos en un formulario modal

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap

Hola Tengo una situación con un proyecto de practica que tengo actualmente donde estamos haciendo entrega de informacion mediantes modales en php, a lo cual tengo este modal para la entrega de datos:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_datosfunc" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal_datosfuncLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal_datosfuncLabel">Informacion del funcionario</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="Cod_funcionario" id="Cod_funcionario"></input>
      </form>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
          
      <?php include 'controlador_datosfunc.php'; ?>
      </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar cambios</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Donde en el form incluido se carga mediante un evento en la pagina original el codigo de usuario que quiero usar para mostrar en la zona del table ('controlador_datosfunc.php' es quien hace la carga de datos) pero no puedo usar el dato para hacer la variable dentro del controlador, mi pregunta es como puedo usar la informacion del form para poder usarlo como variable dentro del controlador, como es un dato oculto que se envía no puedo usar un boton de carga de datos, por lo que intente usar una funcion para la carga, pero no tuve exito.